# For each li in list that contains span with text, remove another span from within that li

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a list of items. 
In each list item, I have spans. 
I want to check if one span contains a string (in this case is : "Account"), to remove another span from that List item only. I am selecting the items by Class, not by Id.

I tried this code:

```
$("ul").find('li .productRelatedToAdditional:contains("Account")').each(function(){
    if ($(".productRelatedToAdditional:contains('Account')").length > 0) {
       $(".productRelatedToAdditional").remove();
       $(".productRelatedTo").remove(); 
    }
});
```

but it is not working. It is removing the elements from all List items.
So I want to remove the span with the Class "productRelatedTo" and the element "productRelatedToAdditional" only from the list items where the span with the class "productRelatedToAdditional" contains the word "Account"

Thank you very much

Comment: Send us the html code too

Comment: I said it's a List.... and each item contains spans. The HTML is generated by JSPs, can't send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : find parent `li` of `productRelatedToAdditional` matched, then find `productRelatedTo` and remove it.

```
$("ul").find('li .productRelatedToAdditional:contains("Account")').each(function(){
       var $parentLi = $(this).closest('li');
       $(this).remove();
       $parentLi.find(".productRelatedTo").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li .productRelatedToAdditional:contains('Account')").each(function(){

    $(this).siblings(".productRelatedToAdditional, .productRelatedTo").remove(); 
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9wj6bx7/2/

Answer (score 1):

see also working code snippet

```js
(function($) {
  $('li').each(function() {
    var string = $(this).find('.productRelatedToAdditional').html();
    console.log(string);
    if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf("active") >= 0) {
      $(this).find('.productRelatedTo').remove();
      $(this).find('.productRelatedToAdditional').remove();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="productRelatedTo">hello1</span>
      <span class="productRelatedToAdditional">active</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="productRelatedTo">hello2</span>
      <span class="productRelatedToAdditional"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="productRelatedTo">hello3</span>
      <span class="productRelatedToAdditional">aCtiVe</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="productRelatedTo">hello4</span>
      <span class="productRelatedToAdditional"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

this should do the job:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var string = $(this).children('.productRelatedToAdditional').html();
    if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf("active") >= 0){
        $(this).children('.productRelatedTo').remove();
        $(this).children('.productRelatedToAdditional').remove();
    }
});
```

greetings timotheus

Comment: This is not working. Thank you anyway :) Bhushan provided the working solution :)

Comment: it works just searched for account instead of active.. and its not case sensitive ;)